# Regex: match a non nested code block

Tags: regex, nested, match

I am currently writing a small texteditor. With this texteditor users are able to create small scripts for a very simple scripting engine.

For a better overview I want to highlight codeblocks with the same command like GoTo(x,y) or Draw(x,y).

To achieve this I want to use Regular Expresions (I am already using it to highlight other things like variables)

Here is my Expression (I know it's very ugly):

```
/(?<!GoTo|Draw|Example)(^(?:GoTo|Draw|Example)\(.+\)*?$)+(?!GoTo|Draw|Example)/gm
```

The "logic":

- (?< !GoTo|Draw|Example) : Negative Lookbehind. No GoTo/Draw/Example command in the line before (*inserted a space to avoid rendering problems)*
- (^(?:GoTo|Draw|Example)(.+)*?$) now macth GoTo/Draw/Example(*)* until line end (even match a comment)
- "+" find last pattern min. one times
- UNTIL in the next line does not contain GoTo/Draw/Example (negative lookahead)

(for testing at regex101.com, finaly I need this for vb.net)
It matches the following:

```
-Code-                    -result-             execpted result
GoTo(5656)               -> MATCH 1            -> MATCH 1
sdsd
GoTo(sdsd) --comment     -> MATCH 2            -> MATCH 2
GoTo(23329);             -> MATCH 3            -> MATCH 2
Test() 
GoTo(12)                 -> MATCH 4            -> MATCH 3
LALA
Draw(23)                 -> MATCH 5            -> MATCH 4
Draw(24)                 -> MATCH 6            -> MATCH 4
Draw(25)                 -> MATCH 7            -> MATCH 4
```

But what I want to achieve is, that the complete "blocks" of the same command are matched. In this case Match 2 & 4 and Match 5 & 6 & 7 should be one match.

Image: Group example:

[image]

Tested with http://regex101.com/, the programming lanuage is vb.net.

Comment: Can you please provide the input text and the expected result? I think there isn't enough information to provide and suggestion here

Comment: Matches 3 & 4 appear to be separated by Test().  Do you mean matches 2 & 3?  Additionally please clarify what language you're using.  In the expression above, `(?.....)` is the regular expression, and `/...../gm` is regular expression syntax in a programming language.

Comment: Finaly I use vb.net, but for testing I am using: http://regex101.com/,if the regex matches correct there I can implement it. Added an Image for a better example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression you are looking for is

```
((?:^GoTo.+\n?)+)|((?:Draw.+\n?)+)
```

You can see this at work [here](http://regex101.com/r/xS3rT1)

The key here is the use of `\n` to match "everything including the end of the line" so you can match across multiple lines. Also note the use of `?:` to get non-capturing inner groups (which are repeated) so we don't end up with inner and outer matches (we only want "the whole block" matched). Finally, the `|` separates an entire block of `Draw` from an entire block of `GoTo`. Obviously if you have other keywords, you can repeat for those as well.